# How to produce a pdf in S5 or statsformat

Tags: geometry, paper-size

The Swedish state paper format S5 has dimensions of 165 x 242 mm. It does not exist as a preset in the geometry package, neither s5paper or statsformat are acceptable options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to manually specify the paper size to geometry:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=242mm]{geometry}
```